# Find pattern inside string regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find if some pattern is exist in the following string

`I123456-sxzzukerrdco86rg-CMafApp-java`

Or `D977058-sxzzukerrdco86rg-CMafApp-java`

I need to find the following

1. if string start with `I977058-`
2. The `I` can be also `D` like `D977058-`
3. the string should be find in the start of the string like I977058-sxzzukerrdco86rg-CMafApp-java , it cannot be in any other part of the string…
4. `zzzz-sxzzukerrdco86rg-CMafApp-java` is not valid
5. `11111-sxzzukerrdco86rg-CMafApp-java` not valid

I try with the following which doesn’t works

I don’t know how to provide pattern which take also the D or I as starting point

```
var res = str.match(/I-/g);
```

Comment: What is the expected output in your case?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - valid or not valid

Comment: Like `/^[ID]\d{6}-sxzzukerrdco86rg-CMafApp-java$/.test(s)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - `sxzzukerrdco86rg-CMafApp-java$` can be any pattern of string i just need to find if it start with `D` or `I` with `7` digit num and after `-` just in this case return valid...

Comment: Then `/^[ID]\d{6}-/.test(s)` should work. Same  as Nina's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check against the two letters and the wanted digits and a dash.

```js
console.log([
    'I123456-sxzzukerrdco86rg-CMafApp-java',
    'D977058-sxzzukerrdco86rg-CMafApp-java',
    'foo'
].map(/./.test.bind(/^[DI]\d{6}-/)));
```

Comment: But the number after the I or D can be change 7 digit  num that can be any num...

Answer (score 0):

Not totally clear what you're trying to match, but the following pattern will match any string that starts with "D" or "I" - the ^ character indicates the start of the string.

```
var res = str.match(/^[ID]/);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[ID]\d+-sxzzukerrdco86rg-CMafApp-java/
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score -1):

Try something like that :

```
/^[ID]/
```

The '^' tells that it is the beginning of the word.
[ID] => get a char in group {I,D}

You can use this website to train and understand regexpressions : https://regex101.com/